# HOW TO: Dynamic RESET of Leaflet layers control

Tags: javascript, jquery, maps, leaflet

Using Leaflet and JQuery Datatables, I am building an embedded page for our CRM. The map and the datatable use THE SAME JSON datasource, and I'm building shared functions to facilitate interactivity between the two libraries.

One of the actions a user can take is to "reload" the table and the map with data queried using a different distance radius. I am successfully reloading the table, and I'm successfully clearing and recreating all my markers and layerGroups, but I can't figure out how to reset (or destroy and recreate) the Layers Control. Either I get no control, or I get a duplicate new control with each reload.

I've declared the control object and an overlayMaps object in the global scope, but if I add  the control to the map with no overlayMaps I can't update it once I've filled the array. If I wait to add the control to the map until the overlayMaps object is filled, then the .addTo(map) function just makes a new control.  I've tried testing for the control's existence, but any remove-from-map method produces a "Node not found" error.

What I really need is an updateMaps() method on the Control object, but that doesn't seem to be in the API.

Anybody got any ideas?

Comment: There's a previous stackoverflow [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15507737) that led to a couple possible solutions to your problem. [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26262146/5403120) in particular seems promising. In essence, you can create a div within your Control and simply update the contents of that as needed by setting its `.innerHTML`. No need to deal with removing/re-creating multiple Control objects.

Comment: Well, sorry to be so dense, but your suggestion only gets me so far... I was able to make the custom div, and I was able to make the layers control object. Now how to I insert the control object into the innerHTML of the custom div?

Comment: What exactly is stopping you from using `addOverlay` and `removeLayer` to manage the state of the `LayerControl`? I don't see the need for recreating/readding more LayerControls.

Comment: Well, I don't know what I did differently, but at snkashis's suggestion I revisited AddOverlay and RemoveLayer, and go them to work.

Snakashis, if you post as an answer, I'll accept it and rep you. Thanks.